# Sharepoint 2010 - "We did not find any results for" keyword

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a single-server deployment of Sharepoint Foundation 2010 (via Microsoft Search Server 2010 Express).

When it comes to searching content in a basic Sharepoint site the stand-alone search page at http://domain/site/search/default.aspx the required results turn up. However when I use "Search this site..." below the ribbon I receive:

We did not find any results for **keyword**.

Is there any way to hook this into the main search results?

**Update:** Unfortunately the below solution has the side effect of causing it to be unable to sync STSSync lists (e.g. Discussions) in Outlook with the error:

Task 'SharePoint' reported error (0x80070005) : 'You do not have permission to view this SharePoint List (XXX - XXX). Contact the SharePoint site administrator.  HTTP 302.' Therefore I must choose one or the other.

Therefore, I can currently have one or the other, but not both.

Comment: What is the url of "Search this site..." results. I ask because I suspect that in the first case you use single-label domain name and in the second it might be not and would require to tell that it is local

Comment: The "Search this site..." is on the home page of the site at https://domain/site/default.aspx, and it redirects to https://domain/site/_layouts/OSSSearchResults.aspx?k=keyword&cs=This%20Site&u=https://internetdomain - one key point you've unearthed is that if I remote the &u=http://internetdomain the results do show up.

Comment: Hi, Solution Evangelist, I was banned from site and lost my discussions.I could not understand: 1)HTTP302 - strange error; have you typed it correctly? 2)Mike Hacker's Blog tells "that the issue is related to security changes made in Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7". But what issue? Can it be connected to http://serverfault.com/questions/170476/windows-server-2008-connecting-to-127-0-0-1/170524#170524 ?

Comment: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserversecurity/thread/ef870972-e634-407c-b4f0-be995bd5f6bf

Comment: http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/xpsecurity/thread/2c0a5748-4ceb-47da-8c51-5f699172b403

Comment: I wrote incorrectly: 2) What are  "the security changes made in Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved!  Due to an issue with the crawler indexing sites with Basic Authentication and Anonymous authentication on Server 2008 R2 (see Mike Hacker's [Blog](http://blog.mikehacker.net/?p=9998)). I've developed a workaround by extending the Extend the Web Application and create a second one at http://netbios:81 with NTLM authentication enabled.

It turns out this was interfering with the search because this wasn't the default on the Alternate Access Mappings so the search scopes weren't working.

Under Central Administration > Edit Public Zone URLs I set the URLs as follows and it works:

Default: http://netbios:81
Intranet: http://netbios
Internet: https://domain
Extranet: http://domain

Comment: Thanks vgv8! I'll be sure to follow SF more closely and become more involved as this is one area where I work a great deal!